# AngularJs ionic получить значение headers

Tags: angularjs, ionic

Нужно из $http запроса получить значение headers: Counts
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Пытаюсь так:

```
$http.get('http://webfather.ru:3000/api/leads?limits=1&domainid=123')
            .success(function (response, status, headers) {
                var getcounts = headers('Counts');
                console.log(getcounts);
});
```

В console.log выводит null
Как получить эту переменную?
В чистом ангуляре все норм, но при билде в ионике, заголовки headers очищаются, и остается только content-type

Answer (score 1):

Дело в том, что CORS не позволяет получить все заголовки. Включите в ответ от сервера следующий заголовок:

```
Access-Control-Expose-Headers:*
```